# JPanels not being drawn

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel

I'm working on a vertical scrolling game, and I'm using a thread to generate new enemies every 2 seconds. Each enemy is an image in a JPanel. For some reason, The generated enemies are not showing up in the JFrame, but they are present. When the player collides with one of the enemies, all the enemies show up.
Here's the code:

```
private void checkCollision() {
    for(AlienShip as : enemies) {
        if(player.getBounds().intersects(as.getBounds()))
            player.setVisible(false);
    }
}

private void setAlien() {
    alien = new AlienShip();
    add(alien);
    enemies.add(alien);
    System.out.println("Enemies: " + enemies.size());
}

public Thread alienGenerator() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // these are being drawn
        setAlien();
    }

    return new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int sleepTime = 2000;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                setAlien(); //these aren't
            }
        }
    });
}


private void gameLoop() {
    alienGenerator().start();
    mainTimer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
            checkCollision();
        }
    });
    mainTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: Beware - more threads doesn't make your code run faster, it's a balancing act.  A "better" solution might be to use the `gameLoop` and calculate the time since the last enemy was spawned and the spawn them as needed.  This has a number of important benefits.  Swing is NOT thread safe, this means that you should not update the UI or something the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: 1) Does the alien have a size and location? 2) Do you invoke repaint() on the panel when you add an alien to the panel?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It always seems that you're **Darned If You Do And Darned If You Don't**. As far as I'm concerned the code you had placed in your [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380769/jpanels-not-being-drawn-in-jframe) was adequate, as a matter of fact, it was still lacking (no PlayerShip Class). The code example in this post does even less justice. Never the less......

Before I get started I just want you to know that I personally would have tackled this task somewhat differently and the meager assistance provided here will be solely based on the code you have already provided in this and previous posts.

The reason you are not seeing your Alien Ships displaying onto the Game Board upon creation is because you don't **revalidate** the board panel. As you currently have your code now this can be done from within the **Board.setAlien()** method where the Alien Ships are added. Directly **under** the code lines:

```
alien = new AlienShip();
add(alien);
enemies.add(alien);
```

add the code line: `revalidate();`, so the code would look like this:

```
alien = new AlienShip();
add(alien);
enemies.add(alien);
revalidate();
```

Your Alien Ships should now display.

> **On A Side Note:**

What is to happen when any Alien Ship actually makes it to the bottom of the Game Board? As a suggestion, have them re-spawn to the top of the game board (serves ya right fer missin em). This can be done from within the **AlienShip.scrollShip()** method by checking to see if the Alien Ship has reached the bottom of the board, for example:

```
public void scrollShip() {
    if (getY() + 1 > this.getParent().getHeight()) { 
        setY(0 - PANEL_HEIGHT);
    }
    else {
        setY(getY() + 1);
    }
}
```

In my opinion, **PANEL_HEIGHT** is the wrong field name to use. I think it would be more appropriate to use something like **ALIEN_SHIP_WIDTH** and **ALIEN_SHIP_HEIGHT**. Same for the variables **panelX** and **panelY**, could be **alienShipX** and **alienShipY**. Food for thought.

As you can see in the code above the current Game Board height is acquired by polling the Game Board's **getHeight()** method with: `this.getParent().getHeight()`. This allows you to change the Game Board size at any time and the Alien Ships will know where that current boundary is when scrolling down. All this then means that the **setResizable(false);** property setting done in the Main Class for the Game's JFrame window can now be resizable: `setResizable(true);`.

You will also notice that when the Alien Ship is re-spawned at top of the Game Board it is actually out of site and it flows into view as it moves downward. I think this is a much smoother transition into the gaming area rather than just popping into view. This is accomplished with the `setY(0 - PANEL_HEIGHT);` code line above. As a matter of fact even when the game initially starts, your Alien Ships should flow into the the gaming area this way and that can be done from within the **AlienShip.initAlienShip()** method by initializing the **panelY** variable to `panelY = -PANEL_HEIGHT;`.

This now takes me to the initialization of the **PANEL_WIDTH** and **PANEL_HEIGHT** fields. The values seem enormous (224 and 250 respectively). Of course you may have set to these sizes for collision testing purposes, etc but I think an image size of 64 x 35 would most likely suffice:

[image]

This image should be a PNG image with a transparent background which then eliminates the need for the `setBackground(Color.BLUE);` code line located within the **AlienShip.initAlienShip()** method.

The **AlienShip.getX()** and **AlienShip.getY()** methods should be overridden:

```
@Override  
public int getX() { ... }

@Override  
public int getY() { ... }
```

I think extending the AlienShip Class to JLabel would be better than to JPanel. To JPanel seems like overkill:

```
public class AlienShip extends JLabel { ... }
```

Adding a background image to the Game Board can add pizazz to the game. This can be achieved by adding the following code to the **Board.paintComponent()** method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon("images/StarBackground.png");
    Image img = imgIcon.getImage();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height, this);
}
```

Images can be [acquired here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=star+background&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMh43kjuLeAhWTOn0KHaffDskQ_AUIDigB&biw=1440&bih=750#imgrc=_).

[image]

This should keep you going for a while. Before to long it'll be Alien mayhem.

[image]

Comment: The revalidate() line fixed it. Thanks! I'm going to add all the other functionality now that this issue is fixed.